# understanding virtual copy constructors

Tags: c++, class, copy-constructor

I'm having trouble understanding what's really happening with the code in a book I'm using to learn C++. Here's the code:

```
class Base
{
    public:
        Base() {};
        virtual ~Base() {};

        virtual Base* Clone() {return new Base(*this);}
};

class Derived
{
    public:
        Derived() {};
        virtual ~Derived() {};

        virtual Base* Clone() {return new Derived(*this);}
};
```

So in this `Clone()` function I understand that the function returns a pointer to a Base class object. What I don't understand is what's happening within that function. When I've previously used `new` as in `int *pInt = new int`, I was under the impression that `new` essentially allocates enough memory on the free store for an integer, then returns that address, applying the address to the pointer `pInt`. With that same logic I'm trying to understand the `new Derived(*this)` portion of the code. So, I think it is allocating enough memory on the free store for a Derived class object, and returning the address, which is then returned by the function `Clone()`.

Why, though, does it pass `*this` through the constructor, if that is a constructor? I understand `*this` means its passing the address of whatever object is being cloned, but I don't understand the syntax of `class_name(address_of_an_object)` in the context of the `new` function.

Could someone please explain what's happening in that portion?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The misunderstanding is here:

> `*this` means its passing the address of whatever object is being cloned

In reality, `this` is the address of the object that is being cloned, but `*this` (note the asterisk) is the result of *dereferencing* that address. So `*this` is of type `Derived &`, it's a reference to the object being cloned, not its address.

Therefore, calling `new Derived(*this)` means that after dynamically allocating space (which is what `new` does), the new space is initialised by the copy constructor `Derived(const Derived &)`, which in this case hasn't actually been user-defined, so the (compiler-generated) default version of the copy constructor is used.

---

To clarify the semantics of `new`: If `C` is a class, then

```
new C;
```

allocates enough space for an object of type `C` and then calls the constructor of `C` to initialise that space. This is part of the semantics of `new`: It always calls the constructor to initialise the newly allocated space.

When you call

```
new C(a,b,c);
```

with some arguments `a`, `b` and `c`, then `new` will call a constructor of `C` that takes these three arguments. If no such constructor has been defined, you'll get a compiler error.

Now in the special case where you call

```
new C(a);
```

with an argument `a` that is itself of type `C&`, `new` will, as always, call the appropriate constructor. The appropriate constructor is either `C(C &)` (if defined), or `C(const C&)` (copy-constructor auto-defined by the compiler).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I guess I don't understand how exactly I'm "calling the copy constructor" with 'new'. If 'Derived(*this)' is merely a reference of the object being cloned, how is 'new' calling a copy constructor? I thought 'new' was just about allocating memory and returning an address, is that not the case?

Comment: _new_ always invokes a constructor. _new Derived()_ invokes default constructor, _new Derived(1,2)_ invokes the constructor _(int,int)_ - that does not exist - and _new Derived(*this)_ is invoking the implicit copy constructor. Everytime you have a constructor of the type _ClassName(const ClassName&)_ it is a copy constructor, if you pass an object of _ClassName_ to construct another object of _ClassName_ it will be copied.

Comment: @user1997615 What André said. I've also added a clarification to the answer.

Comment: Thank you both for the clarification, this lesson makes much more sense now. Really appreciate the help.