# copy constructor copy pointer to abstract class

Tags: class, pointers, constructor, copy, abstract

Say I have a class General, which holds a pointer to an abstract class, *_abstract.
If I want to implement General copy constructor, how is it done?

I try this but it fails:

```
General::General(const General &other)
{
    *_abstract = *other._abstract;
}
```

I also tried:

```
General::General(const General &other)
{
    *_abstract = new Abstract();
    *_abstract = *other._abstract;
}
```

which is impossible because of the abstract class initialization (no constructor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to deep copy the abstract class then add a virtual clone function to the abstract class and copy it with that.

[understanding virtual copy constructors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14720110/understanding-virtual-copy-constructors)

Comment: I found this link that gives an example of what you said, thanks!
http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/copy-of-abc-via-clone.html